# Number of words preceding a particular word

Tags: java, string, cpu-word

While indexOf(the) in java gives me number of characters preceding "the" in the sentence *One day I saw the beautiful bird*, I would like to know the way of getting the number of words preceding it. For example, the output for the given sentence would be 4!

Thank you.

Comment: Well, I can use word iterator to trace the number of words and add up the pile until I find "the" in a sentence. But is there any other easier way? Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is your definition of "word"?

Comment: =) One day I saw the beautiful bird- has 7 words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [java.util.Scanner](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5,0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

Scan and count the words until you hit *the*

**EDIT**: very simple example (and not tested ;-)

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.println(indexOfWord("One day I saw the beautiful bird", "the"));
}

private static int indexOfWord(String input, String word) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(input);
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\S*");
    int count = 0;
    while (s.hasNext(p)) {
        if (word.equals(s.next(p)))
            return count;
        count++;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: I think `countWords` is a poor choice of name for this method. To me, `countWords` says "How many times does this word occur in the target string?" As someone consuming your API, I would be shocked if a method called `countWords` returned a -1!

Comment: @glowcoder, yes you are absolute right! THX for your attention. I’ll change it. _My fingers established a direct memory access to my brain and wrote the lines down quickly without any cognitive interaction._

Comment: This is a splendid solution. Thanks Sascha!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this is to count the space characters preceding "the".

```
One day I saw the
   ^   ^ ^   ^
```

There are 4 spaces, so there are 4 words.

Of course, you might have to add some special handling for multiple spaces between words or punctuation marks.

Comment: What about the input `"One  day  I  saw  the"`?

Comment: Haha, I'm sorry, it appears the auto formatting took them out. There was supposed to be spaces there. So like, `"One--day--I--saw--the"` just with spaces instead of dashes.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant with "special handling for multiple spaces". In this case, you'd need a state machine-like routine instead of simple space counting. But that's not much more effort and personally, I would still prefer it to regular expressions or similar "complex" solutions.

Comment: Heh... must be late in the day, I completely didn't see that. Well good on ya then.

Answer (score 1):

You must fist split the string into words, then you can find the index of the word.

```
public int indexOfWord(String sentence, String word) {
  return Arrays.asList(sentence.split("\\s+")).indexOf(word);
}
```

If you need a more efficient approach, see the `Scanner` pointed by Sascha.

Answer (score 0):

Use `String.split()` using a space as the delimiter. Then count the number of elements in the returned array before you get to the word.